# Difference between cardinal and ordinal

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I think this question has already been asked, but I do not find any precise trace of it. I do not get the difference between cardinal and ordinal numbers: why aren't they both matching the equivalence classes under the relation "being in bijection with"?

Comment: Does this help? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2744577/simple-definition-of-ordinal-and-cardinal-numbering

Comment: Ordinal numbers list the objects in an order: the first, the second, etc, while cardinals count the numerosity of collections of objects: how many? For the finite case the two "numbers" coincide; not so for infinite collections.

Comment: An ordinal represents the "position" of a  of a number in a set with respect to order, and a cardinal represents its size regardless of order. A set of fruits that contains: $\{\text{apple, mango, banana, grape}\}$ has a cardinality of four. If we say that it is well-ordered, and that $apple$ is the least element, and the others are successive (so, mango = apple + 1) then they've the ordinality of the natural numbers. In other words, you look in a set and ask, where is the 7th element? That's ordinality. You look at the set and ask how many elements are in it, that's cardinality.

Answer (score 8):

This is not easy to understand, because in finite sets there is not much of a difference.
The idea is that for ordinal numbers you also have a relation between the numbers, so you can put them in line.
Let's take as an example the numbers
$$
0,\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4},\frac{7}{8},...,\frac{2^n-1}{2^n},...,1.
$$
Now this set has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{N}$ (because there is a bijection) but if you wanted to find a bijection $\Phi$ to the natural numbers preserving the order of numbers, this would not be possible. Preserving order means $ x < y \Longrightarrow \Phi(x) < \Phi(y)$.
It's not possible, as you have the biggest element 1, which would need to be bigger than all natural numbers (but it's not obvious).
In a way the ordinal numbers are a finer tool to describe how big a set is. For example $ 2 \omega + 5$ has the same ordinal number as
$$
0,\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4},\frac{7}{8},...,\frac{2^n-1}{2^n},...,1,1+\frac{1}{2},...,1+\frac{2^n-1}{2^n},...,2,3,4,5,6
$$
has the same ordinal number as
$$
\frac{7}{8},...,\frac{2^n-1}{2^n},...,1,1+\frac{1}{2},...,1+\frac{2^n-1}{2^n},...,2,3,4,5,6
$$
because it has to "limit-dents" and afterwards 5 elements.

Answer (score 3):

If I need numbers to count "how many items do I have" then I use cardinal numbers. If I need to make a list, or a enumeration, I use ordinal.

For finite sets there is no difference. If you have cardinality $3$, you can have the list: $[a,b,c]$ or $[a,c,b]$ or $[b,c,a]$ or ... but they have the same structure, so there is only one ordinal corresponding to the cardinal $3$.

If you have the set $\mathbb{N}=\{0,1,2...\}$ and you add one item $x$, the amount of item is the same as before, because is again $\aleph_0$. However, if you are working with list things are different.

You can decide that $x$ is between $2$ and $3$, in this case the new list $0,1,2,x,3,4,...$ is essentially the same as the original $\mathbb{N}$.
You can decide that $x$ is bigger than any previous number, in this case the list $0,1,2,3,...,x$ is different from $\mathbb{N}$. For example, the new list has a maximum, $\mathbb{N}$ is unbounded.

So there are essentially different way to put an order over a infinite set, so you can't collapse concept of ordinal and cardinal.

Comment: I know this answer is not formal, I focused on the idea. Instead of list I should have referred to total ordered set and isomorphism...

Comment: I found somewhere non-standard analysis using "numerosities", and proving that odd numbers are 1/2 aleph_0
 (a paper by Vieri Bienci here: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiEg-KZieDyAhXGxqQKHXqpAw4QFnoECAQQAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpeople.dm.unipi.it%2Fdinasso%2Fpapers%2F13.pdf&usg=AOvVaw31aE3CukmsmGmPj2akZwtP)